getting error while converting string to datetime using parse method
String dateString = '2024-09-24T14:30:00.000Z';
DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.parse(dateString);
System.debug('Parsed DateTime: ' + dateTimeValue);


Line: 2, Column: 1 System.TypeException: Invalid date/time:
2024-09-24T14:30:00.000Z


I've downvoted for lack of research.

You should read through the documentation on the Datetime class. The parse() method says the following

Constructs a Datetime from the given String in the local time zone and in the format of the user locale.


This example uses parse to create a Datetime from a date passed in as a string and that is formatted for the English (United States) locale. You may need to change the format of the date string if you have a different locale.
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011, 11:46 AM');
String myDtString = dt.format();
system.assertEquals(myDtString, '10/14/2011, 11:46 AM');


No locales use the ISO-8601 datetime format.
The closest thing we have would be Datetime.valueOf(), but you would need to remove the T (replace it with a space) and the Z.
e.g. Datetime dt = Datetime.valueOf('2024-09-24 06:50:00.000');
